# Weren’t or wasn’t usage

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Which is correct to say,

> If (singular something) *wasn’t* or *weren’t* bad enough,…?

Comment: I suspect that even many of those who those who prefer irrealis (and counterfactual) 'If I were you, I'd ...' would use 'I suspect the police here would do the same if the situation wasn't under control'.